# Jenkins Groovy Renderer Dynamic Parameters: List Box with multi option

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
def options = [‘Option1’, ‘Option2’, ‘Option3’]
```

I would like to create a dynamic GROOVY based Parameter in Jenkins, something like:

```
<select type="text" class="setting-input" name="value">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option2</option>
</select>
```

But I would like to to write it in generic way using a kind of loop of $options .

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dynamic build parameters you can use [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/). It also supports dynamic HTML rendering for advanced use cases. But your example doesn't need that.

Example below.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
            description: 'Select the options below', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: false, 
            name: 'Env', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return["Option1","Option12","Option3","Option4"]'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{
          echo 'Hello'
          echo "${params.Env}"
        } }
      }
  }
}
```